# Unsure how to frame an SQL Query for the mentioned task

Tags: mysql, sql

These are my tables:

```
concerts (
    concert_id: INT, 
    name: VARCHAR(200), 
    venue: VARCHAR(200), 
    schedule: DATETIME) 

singers (
    singer_id: INT, 
    name: VARCHAR(200), 
    gender: ENUM('male', 'female', 'other')) 

performances(singer_id: INT, 
    concert_id: INT) 
Foreign keys: {singer_id} to singers {concert_id} to concerts
```

I’m trying to come up with a query to 
List all concerts of a singer who performed in more than 5 concerts in the year 2018. 
(The 5 and 2018 are user determined variables/ I’m testing it out for these for now)
 I tried multiple attempts and nothing seems to come close to the task I'm trying to achieve. Any help with regard to the same would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

- In a sub-select query ([Derived table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/derived-tables.html)), we can first determine all the `singer_id` value(s) who has more than 5 concerts in the year 2018. We use `Group By` with [`Count(...)`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/counting-rows.html) function, to determine the total number of concerts for a `singer_id`. **Note** that if you have duplicate row(s) for a `singer_id` and `concert_id` combination in the `performances` table, then you will need to use `Count(Distinct ...)` function. Now, we can use `Having` clause to consider only those singer(s) where count is more than 5.
- Now, simply `Join` this derived table result-set to the main tables, in order to get list of concerts from the year 2018.

Try the following query:

```
SELECT c1.*, s1.*
FROM 
concerts AS c1 
JOIN performances AS p1 ON p1.concert_id = c1.concert_id 
JOIN 
(
  SELECT
    s.singer_id, 
    COUNT(c.concert_id) AS num_concerts 
  FROM 
    singers AS s 
  JOIN performances AS p ON p.singer_id = s.singer_id 
  JOIN concerts AS c ON c.concert.id = p.concert_id AND 
                        c.schedule >= '2018-01-01' AND 
                        c.schedule < '2019-01-01'
  GROUP BY s.singer_id 
  HAVING num_concerts > 5
) AS dt ON dt.singer_id = p1.singer_id 
JOIN singers AS s1 ON s1.id = dt.singer_id 
WHERE c1.schedule >= '2018-01-01' 
  AND c1.schedule < '2019-01-01'
```

Comment: ...why are you including `singers` in the nested query?  That shouldn't be necessary, and is probably hurting performance (as `name` isn't going to be on a useful index for grouping).  You shouldn't need to specify `DISTINCT` on the count either, given the datamodel presented.  Also, note that `YEAR(date_column)` is **likely** to invalidate the use of an index for the range - much better to do something like `date_column >= $start_of_year AND date_column < $start_of_next_year`.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse agreed on the `Year(date_column)` point. Regarding `singers`, I believe that OP will need it to identify concerts and its singers. Since OP has not given out expected output, I decided to get all data (which I felt would be needed for display purposes)

Comment: Yes, presumably you need singers in the output - I just would have done that join on the outer level.  And note that `BETWEEN` is the wrong choice here: the type is `DATETIME`, meaning if the concert is actually stored with a non-midnight time on December 31st, it will not be included.  It's much safer to do `< '2019-01-01'`, which avoids the problem entirely.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse incorporated the changes. Thanks for optimization tips